# Select drop down value in php foreach

Tags: php, html

I have a drop down generated with php.

```
<select name="diploma" id="diploma-<? echo $edu['id']; ?>">
                    <? foreach($diplomas->result_array() as $diploma) {
          echo "<option    value=".$diploma['id'].">".$diploma['name']."</option>";
                            } ?>
</select>
```

I also have `<? echo $edu['diploma']; ?>` which is a value from the database. I want to add `selected="selected"` to the option in the drop down which matches this value. Should I just use jquery? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check inside the loop like this:

```
<select name="diploma" id="diploma-<? echo $edu['id']; ?>">
    <? 
    foreach($diplomas->result_array() as $diploma) 
        {
            if($edu['diploma']==$diploma['name'])
            {
                echo "<option selected ='selected' value=".$diploma['id'].">".$diploma['name']."</option>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<option value=".$diploma['id'].">".$diploma['name']."</option>";
            }
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Or to make the code shorter:

```
<select name="diploma" id="diploma-<? echo $edu['id']; ?>">
    <? 
    foreach($diplomas->result_array() as $diploma) 
        {
            $selected = ($edu['diploma']==$diploma['name']) ? " selected='selected' " : "" ;
            echo "<option $selected value=".$diploma['id'].">".$diploma['name']."</option>";
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same PHP code:

```
<select name="diploma" id="diploma-<? echo $edu['id']; ?>">
    <? foreach($diplomas->result_array() as $diploma) {
        echo "<option value=".$diploma['id'];
        if ($edu['diploma'] == $diploma['name']) {
            echo 'selected="selected"';
        }
        echo ">".$diploma['name']."</option>";
    } ?>
</select>
```

The code compares `$diploma['name']` with your `$edu['diploma']` variable for each option and outputs `selected="selected"` if they're the same.

Depending on the contents of `$edu['diploma']` you need to compare it with one thing or another. If `$edu['diploma']` contains the `id` change `$diploma['name']` to `$diploma['id']`.

If `$edu['diploma']` contains the diploma object itself, you need to compare this way: `$edu['diploma']['id'] == $diploma['id']`

Answer (score 1):

That's what I came up with:

```
<select name="diploma" id="diploma-<? echo $edu['id']; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($diplomas->result_array() as $diploma) {
    //echo "<option value='{$diploma['id']}'>{$diploma['name']}</option>";
    echo "<option value='{$diploma['id']}";
    if ($edu['diploma'] === $diploma['name']) {
        echo " selected";
    }
    echo ">{$diploma['name']}</option>\n";
} ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="diploma" id="diploma-<? echo $edu['id']; ?>">
   <?php foreach($diplomas->result_array() as $diploma) {
      $selected = $diploma['id'] == $edu['diploma'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; 
      echo '<option value="' . $diploma['id'] . '"' . $selected . '>' . $diploma['name'] . '</option>';
     } ?>
</select>
```

Do a check inside the loop, and echo the selected attribute if the values match. Note, I'm using a [ternary statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in the test.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, try this;

```
<select name="diploma" id="diploma-<? echo $edu['id']; ?>">
<?
$selected = $edu['diploma'];
foreach($diplomas->result_array() as $diploma) {
  if($diploma['name'] == $selected){
    echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$diploma['id'].'">'.$diploma['name']."</option>";
  }else{
    echo '<option value="'.$diploma['id'].'">'.$diploma['name']."</option>";
  }
}
?>
</select>
```